# Include a text/event-stream with restify - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, api, request, restify

I'm working in NodeJs and I'm making a JSONClient request with [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#JsonClient) to an API and I want to send the `text/event-stream` header in order to suscribe me to the server responses.

A common call to the API without that header looks like this:

```
var client = restify.createJSONClient({
    url: 'http://api.example.com'
});

return client.get('/getResource', 
        function (err, req, res, obj) {
   //Do stuff            
}
```

Doing this I get an answer but it's not the final one, for example I could get "working", "busy" or "doing-something" so I want to suscribe me to the server responses and when the response will finish  then "do the stuff I need with the data".

**Is there a way to send the headers on a get request (JSONClient) in restify?**

I'd tried something like this but seems not to be working

```
client.headers["content-type"] = 'text/event-stream';
```

I don't know if I'm been clear enough but I need the equivalent to:

```
curl -H "accept:text/event-stream" http://api.example.com/getResource
```

By the way, I'm stuck with restify since I'm using [node-workflow](https://github.com/kusor/node-workflow).

I want to avoid making polling as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it with `restify`, it seems that they don't implemented, otherwise I solved with `eventsource` and I want to share that solution:

```
var es = new EventSource('http://api.example.com/createAccount');
es.on('status', function(e) {
  // status event
  console.log(e.data);
}).on('result', function(e) {
  // result event
  console.log(e.data);
}).on('error', function() {
  console.log('ERROR!');
});
```

In this way the streaming is `infinite` and when the server stops responding the `error` function is called (infinite times). Note that we don't need to set the headers. It's something that `eventsource` already does.

Thanks to [@mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex) who answer in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110772/best-way-to-do-an-asynchronous-curl-in-nodejs/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was able to get a restify server working with Server Sent Events, by adding the following after creating the server:

```
server.acceptable.push('text/event-stream');
```